# Should comments inserted as inline edits be flagged, deleted, or left alone?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, comments

https://serverfault.com/posts/457235/revisions

This question included a comment as an inline edit: "Thanks for all your input and discussion on the subject..."

We as a community tend to frown upon such behavior.

When I reviewed this question, I could see three possible courses of action:

2. Flag the question for an actual moderator to convert the inline comment into a real comment.
3. Nuke the inline comment and leave a comment explaining why it was deleted.
4. Leave it alone.

Which is most appropriate?

Comment: I suppose this is about comments that are not intended to update the actual question and do not clarify details related to the question?

Comment: @Zoredache Correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO comments like this one should not be part of the question.
[image]
They're comments, and should be left as such. I say "Nuke with extreme prejudice!" and optionally leave a polite note inviting the OP to re-post as a proper comment.

---

Caveat: My hatred for commentary in questions, equalled only by my hatred for LiveJournal-style `Edit # . . .` notes, is trumped by my hatred for dragging ancient questions back to the front page.  If we're talking about a question from 2009 it's probably better to leave it alone.

Comment: Let the avalanche of corrected questions from 20**10** begin!

Comment: Oh, dear. I just looked at the [revisions list](http://serverfault.com/posts/457235/revisions), and it turns out that the inline comment was added by a moderator, probably in response to a "not an answer" flag. It was not added by the original asker. Mr. Chairman, please let the record show that I didn't *intend* to start a war.

Comment: @MilesErickson It wasn't me, was it? I try to keep my multiple personalities in check but they don't talk to each other so sometimes things get strange...

Comment: @HopelessN00b Markdown ate your babies?

Comment: No, markdown just sucks.  Won't let me bold part of a word, so... that's as good as it gets.  Mucking farkdown.

Answer (score 4):

Oh dear it looks like I wasn't sufficiently caffinated when I dealt with that flag and clicked the wrong option :(

Anyway to answer your question - burninate them.

Comment: Well done sir. Well done indeed.

Comment: This is why the ***DELETE*** buttons need to be BIGGER!

Comment: @voretaq7: and **RED**